# Best way for UI program to check for internal event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, events

I have a WinForms application that is the UI layer running over the logic layers.

My application is a client-server IM program. When the internal program accepts an incoming connection request I'd like the UI to be updated by a simple button text change. The issue is the separation of concerns, decoupling.

One way to do this would be to expose an internal boolean that is changed by the logic layer when it has processed a request and is constantly checked by the UI on its own thread.

This doesn't seem like the best way to me, I assume there are much better built in ways for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose a delegate in the "internal" program:

```
public Action<bool> RequestProcessed { get; set; }
```

Somewhere in your internal code when a request is processed

```
if(RequestProcessed != null)
   RequestProcessed(true);
```

In the gui you create a method

```
public void SomethingHappend(bool processed) {
  // Do gui stuff
  if(processed) {
  }
  else {
  }
}
```

In the gui, subscribe like this:

```
innerInstance.RequestProcessed = SomethingHappened;
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works perfectly.